# Find any key from a hashmap in a file using java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I want to find a key(to be taken from hashmap) in a file using java 8. If any key is found in the file it should print true. Below is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fileName = "C:\\Users\\ABC\\Desktop\\Paper_R2_Final.txt";
    Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
    myMap.put("ecological", "myFirstKey");
    myMap.put("Survey", "mySecondKey");
    myMap.put("Worth", "myThirdKey");


    //read file into stream, try-with-resources
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName),StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)) {

        myMap.forEach((k,v)->System.out.println("key: " + k + ", value: " + v));

        //Problem in the below line
        System.out.println(stream.anyMatch(line->line.contains((CharSequence) myMap.keySet())));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: `line.contains((CharSequence) myMap.keySet())` What do you think this does?

Comment: It is giving me the class cast exception. I understand that but pardon me i am very new to java 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fileName = "C:\\Users\\ABC\\Desktop\\Paper_R2_Final.txt";
    Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
    myMap.put("ecological", "myFirstKey");
    myMap.put("Survey", "mySecondKey");
    myMap.put("Worth", "myThirdKey");

    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(myMap.keySet());
    //if the line contains any of the keys
    Predicate<String> p = (str) -> myList.stream().anyMatch(key -> str.contains(key));

    //read file into stream, try-with-resources
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName),StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)) {
        boolean foundAKey = stream.anyMatch(p);
        if(foundAKey) {
            //a key is found
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: @AnuragSharma Cheers!

Comment: This code in searching the word wherever it is found. Suppose I my key is "event" and i found prevent in the file it is giving me match there as well. How can I restrict it to the whole word only.

Comment: I just modified your code to use predicate. Modify your predicate method to your needs. Instead of using contains method you should write your method to find if there is a word with the key. Google to get the answer.

Comment: I am using the matches() function to check for any regulary expression. Now, my predicate looks like:
Predicate<String> p = (str) -> mapKeyList.stream().anyMatch(key -> str.matches(".*"+File.separator+"b"+key+File.separator+"b.*"));

Answer (score 1):

`myMap.keySet()` is giving you a Set, which is a collection. Casting it to a CharSequence makes no sense and will not give you what you are expecting.

One way of doing what you want would be to tokenize your line (for example split on the spaces), and check if your keySet contains the tokens one by one.

Some pseudo java code :

```
keySet = myMap.keySet();
for each line in the file {
    tokens = line.split(" ");
    for each token in tokens {
        if keySet.contains(token) {
            // Do whatever you want
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know it will work but i want to do it by java-8 way

Comment: I have updated my code to use predicate. It may be sillybut i am just trying the different ways to do this using java8.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
        Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)
            .anyMatch(line -> myMap.keySet().stream().anyMatch(line::contains));
```

Comment: This code in searching the word wherever it is found. Suppose I my key is "event" and i found prevent in the file it is giving me match there as well. How can I restrict it to the whole word only.